# How to fix the height of a div so that adding data dynamically to it doesn't change it's height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a simple calculator and am almost done with it except I cannot fix its screen height. When I enter the data, the height of the calculator screen changes. To reproduce the problem, you can try adding 1 + 2. I have been attempting adding min-height and max-height but to no avail. I can fix its height with js, but I want a pure CSS solution. Here is the code:

```js
let screen = document.getElementById("screen");
let firstArg = document.querySelector(".firstArg");
let operator = document.querySelector(".operator");
let secondArg = document.querySelector(".secondArg");
let numberBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".data-number");
let acBtn = document.querySelector(".ac");
let clearBtn = document.querySelector(".clear");
let backBtn = document.querySelector(".back");
let decimalBtn = document.querySelector(".decimal");
let equalBtn = document.querySelector(".equal");
let operationBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".operation");
let regex = /[+-/*]/;
let digits = /[0-9]/;

numberBtns.forEach(n => n.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (firstArg.innerHTML === "0") {
    firstArg.innerHTML = "";
  }
  if (operator.textContent === "" && firstArg.clientWidth + 40 < screen.offsetWidth) {
    firstArg.append(n.textContent);
  } else if (operator.textContent && secondArg.clientWidth + 40 < screen.offsetWidth) {
    secondArg.append(n.textContent);
  }
}));

decimalBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (!firstArg.textContent.includes(".") && operator.textContent === "") {
    firstArg.append(decimalBtn.textContent);
  } else if (!secondArg.textContent.includes(".") && operator.textContent) {
    secondArg.append(decimalBtn.textContent);
  }
});

operationBtn.forEach(n => n.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (!regex.test(operator.textContent)) {
    operator.append(n.textContent);
    firstArg.append(" ");
    firstArg.append(operator.textContent);
  }
}))

equalBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  let firstParam = firstArg.textContent.split(" ")[0];
  let oper = operator.textContent;
  let secondParam = secondArg.textContent;
  if (secondParam == "") return;
  solve(firstParam, oper, secondParam);
})

document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  if (e.key == "+") {
    if (!regex.test(operator.textContent)) {
      operator.append(e.key);
      firstArg.append(" ");
      firstArg.append(operator.textContent);
    }
  }
  if (e.key == "/") {
    if (!regex.test(operator.textContent)) {
      operator.append(e.key);
      firstArg.append(" ");
      firstArg.append(operator.textContent);
    }
  }
  if (e.key == "-") {
    if (!regex.test(operator.textContent)) {
      operator.append(e.key);
      firstArg.append(" ");
      firstArg.append(operator.textContent);
    }
  }
  if (e.key == "*") {
    if (!regex.test(operator.textContent)) {
      operator.append(e.key);
      firstArg.append(" ");
      firstArg.append(operator.textContent);
    }
  }
  if (digits.test(e.key)) {
    if (firstArg.innerHTML === "0") {
      firstArg.innerHTML = "";
    }
    if (operator.textContent === "" && firstArg.clientWidth + 40 < screen.offsetWidth) {
      firstArg.append(e.key);
    } else if (operator.textContent && secondArg.clientWidth + 40 < screen.offsetWidth) {
      secondArg.append(e.key);
    }
  }
  if (e.code === "Enter") {
    let firstParam = firstArg.textContent.split(" ")[0];
    let oper = operator.textContent;
    let secondParam = secondArg.textContent;
    if (secondParam == "") return;
    solve(firstParam, oper, secondParam);
  }
})

function solve(first, oper, second) {
  switch (oper) {
    case "-":
      firstArg.innerHTML = `${((Number(first) * 10 - Number(second) * 10) / 10).toFixed(1)}`;
      operator.textContent = "";
      secondArg.textContent = "";
      break;
    case "+":
      firstArg.innerHTML = `${((Number(first) * 10 + Number(second) * 10) / 10).toFixed(1)}`;
      operator.textContent = "";
      secondArg.textContent = "";
      break;
    case "/":
      firstArg.innerHTML = `${((Number(first) * 10 / Number(second) * 10) / 10).toFixed(1)}`;
      operator.textContent = "";
      secondArg.textContent = "";
      break;
    case "*":
      firstArg.innerHTML = `${((Number(first) * 10 * Number(second) * 10) / 10).toFixed(1)}`;
      operator.textContent = "";
      secondArg.textContent = "";
      break;
  }
}

backBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if ((operator.textContent || firstArg.textContent.length > 1) && secondArg.textContent == "") {
    operator.innerHTML = "";
    let remaining = firstArg.textContent.slice(0, firstArg.textContent.length - 1).trim();
    firstArg.innerHTML = "";
    firstArg.innerHTML = remaining;
  } else if (firstArg.textContent.length === 1 && secondArg.textContent == "") {
    firstArg.innerHTML = "0";
  } else if (secondArg.textContent) {
    let remaining = secondArg.textContent.slice(0, secondArg.textContent.length - 1).trim();
    secondArg.innerHTML = "";
    secondArg.innerHTML = remaining;
  }
})

window.onload = function() {
  firstArg.innerHTML = 0;
}
acBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  firstArg.innerHTML = 0;
  secondArg.innerHTML = "";
  operator.textContent = "";
})
```

```css
.claculator {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 70px 1fr;
  grid-gap: 35px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 350px;
  height: 370px;
  border-radius: 27px;
  padding: 12px 9px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #191a1c;
}

#screen {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 70px;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#funBtns {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 50px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 30px);
  grid-gap: 20px 40px;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  background-color: #191a1c;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  transition: 200ms ease-out;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.button-plus {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

#screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  row-gap: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.firstArg {
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-overflow: clip;
}

.secondArg {
  float: right;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: rgb(24, 22, 22);
}

.operator {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="calculator.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="claculator">
    <div id="screen">
      <span class="firstArg"></span>
      <span class="operator"></span>
      <span class="secondArg"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="funBtns">
      <button class="button ac">AC</button>
      <button class="button clear">Clear</button>
      <button class="button back">Back</button>
      <button class="operation">/</button>
      <button class="data-number">1</button>
      <button class="data-number">2</button>
      <button class="data-number">3</button>
      <button class="operation">*</button>
      <button class="data-number">4</button>
      <button class="data-number">5</button>
      <button class="data-number">6</button>
      <button class="operation">-</button>
      <button class="data-number">7</button>
      <button class="data-number">8</button>
      <button class="data-number">9</button>
      <button class="operation button-plus">+</button>
      <button class="button decimal">.</button>
      <button class="data-number">0</button>
      <button class="button equal">=</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `#screen { height : 80px }` ??

Comment: @JeremThille I am using min-height in `#screen` so that the content doesn't overflow. Setting `#screen {height : 80px }` would cause an overflow.

Comment: But you can't constraint the height, then add content and expect the content to not overflow. Not sure what you have in mind. If you set `min-height`, you are explicitely expecting it to have a _minimum_ height, in other words, its height can be greater. You explicitely tell it that it _can_ have a greater height. What you want sounds incompatible (freeze the dimensions AND the content doesn't overflow).

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes, I know that adding min-height means setting minimum height. I have set min-height because nothing else seems to work out. Setting `height` overflows the content and max-height also does the same, however, min-height only changes the height when the data is added, it doesn't make the content overflow or go outside the screen.

Comment: @JeremyThille This is what I want to achieve. I want the data to be added, but the height should remain the same. `min-height` does this, but partially.

Comment: Why are you not simply applying `overflow: hidden;`, along with a fixed `height`
?

Comment: `I want the data to be added, but the height should remain the same.` --> `height:80px` does EXACTLY this. But then, you want the content to not overflow, so you allow the height to be greater. But you don't want the height to be greater. But you don't want the content to overflow. You can't have both. Either (the height is fixed AND the content WILL overflow) OR (the content won't overflow because the height increases). You can't have both, it's not logical.

Comment: @connexo Ok so. I used fixed height and `overflow:hidden` and it solved the issue but I had to increase the height of the screen, which was already happening in the above case, but now we increased it manually.

Comment: Oh you want overflowing content to be _hidden_? You never specified this...

Comment: Thank you, JeremyThille and connexo. Your input helped solve the issue. Yes, @Jeremy, I wanted the overflowing content to be hidden. Sorry for not being able to get my point across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the font size to 1 rem

```
.secondArg {
  float: right;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: rgb(24, 22, 22)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the font-size for #screen equal to 1rem
then height to 1rem(if you want screen to be one line high) or 2rem(for two line high)
1rem = :root font-size in pixel.
Since you have added padding(and apparently there are two #screen), add padding height in terms of rem to height as well.
**Total screen height**= *height(in rem)* + *padding(in rem)*
Link for rem to pixel conversion: http://www.standardista.com/px-to-rem-conversion-if-root-font-size-is-16px/.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the css value for `max-height` to the div's class or id.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work.

Comment: try ```#screen {
    flex-direction: row;
```